# Calculate Income Effect and Substitution Effect

Tags: microeconomics, consumer-theory

In the lecture my professor shows a utility function $u(c,n)=\ln c - an$, where $c$ is consumption and $n$ is working hour, and says that for this kind of preference the income effect and the substitution effect cancel out exactly so that changes in wage $w$ does not affect labor supply.

I want to see exactly why and how and thus try to solve the consumer problem and to calculate the income effect and substitution effect. However then I find this isn't like the usual consumer problem because income $I=wn$ is a function of $n$. Then does income effect $dn/dI$ make any sense? I am totally confused and want to know how to calculate the income effect and the substitution effect towards $c$ and $n$ respectively.

(I know that if I replace $c$ with $wn$ and solve the maximization problem then the solution $n$ is not a function of $w$. But I still don't know what are the income and substitution effects?)

Comment: There is a concept called the "endowment income effect" that is relevant here. You can read about it in Hal Varian's Intermediate Economics (Chapter: Buying and Selling) or in [these slides](https://www.ne.su.se/polopoly_fs/1.317090.1485340542!/menu/standard/file/Lecture2_170124.pdf#page=20) that I found.